# GWT: Internet Explorer 9 issue with Facebook application

Tags: javascript, facebook, gwt, iframe, internet-explorer-9

I have developed a facebook application using GWT and tryied to render it through IE9. It works fine if I run it stand-alone, but when I try to access it through facebook iframe it doesn't work. I've been searching up and down finding no answers.

When trying to access it (IE9) I got the following error displayed in an alert pop-up: "SCRIPT5022: DOM Exception: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR(5)"

Hope somebody could help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your <head></head>:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

If this works, look at your scripting syntax, IE9 is processing JavaScript differently now, it just doesn't like any kind of syntax errors when in the past it just failed silently.

Comment: I've tryied that but nothing has happened. I also tryied to include <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Emulate8" >, but it's no good. Thanks anyway man.

Comment: Anybody found some light on this? I really need a solution. As I could see in debug mode, the compatibility mode is forced to IE9 no matter if you had added a meta property inside head tag.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I've upgraded GWT to version 2.4.0 and recompiling.

Thanks anyway